# Creating UIWebview programmatically and using it to do a couple of things then destroy it?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

Is it possible to create a hidden UIWebView programmatically and then release it(destroy it completely deallocating all of it's memory) when I have used it? If so, could you give some tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems odd that you want to use a hidden `UIWebView` object for some task when the main purpose of an `UIWebView` object is to present the html content. The answer to your question is yes. You can create them and remove them programmatically just like any other view as @Nil has mentioned but it seems your main purpose behind this is to get the content. If that's so, you have many other ways you can get that content without having to create a `UIWebView` object. You can use `NSString`'s `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` method to get the contents of the url into a string which you can parse and use. `NSData` has a similar method. However to use these you will have to perform them in the background otherwise they will block the main thread. The most obvious and better way would be to use `NSURLConnection` or its popular counterpart `ASIHTTPRequest`.

Comment: Why I need to use webview is, because I need to run AJAX to get some info. I guess I can't really do anything else.

Comment: Interesting use case. I have heard (haven't used it myself) about `JavaScriptCore` and that it can be used by your app if you manually include it. Seems like it could be of help. Have you considered it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create and destroy a uiwebview as any other uiview.